# Dimension too large for a simple cubic formula

Tags: pgfplots, dimensions

This is the plot I'm working on:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        samples=200,
        xlabel={\(x\)},
        xmin=-0.5,xmax=3.5,
        ylabel={\(y\)},
        ymin=-0.5,ymax=2.5,
    ]
        \addplot [green] {(x - 2)^3 + 1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I use `ymin=-1.5` or any negative value smaller than `-1`, the plot renders just fine. However, it complains that `Dimension too large` when I use `ymin=-0.5` as above.

I read the `pgfplots` docs, section 2.6.2, and still can't find the solution.

Comment: Yo need to define domain of the your function, for example `\addplot [domain=-1.5:3] {(x - 2)^3 + 1};` works fine ...

Comment: @Zarko thanks! I skimmed the first 50 pages of the docs again and still can't find that `domain` is required...

Comment: It's not generally required, as it has a default value (`-5:5`). I don't know why it crashes with your example though, seems a bit odd ...

Comment: @TorbjørnT., with default domain  the values of function becomes to big. If you add `restrict y to domain=0:12` to axis option, than it works. I will write an  answer asap.

Comment: @Zarko That cannot be the problem, if you set `ymin=-1.5` as Minh said, or remove `ymin`/`ymax` and `xmin`/`xmax` altogether, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that is really odd. It seems that there is some bug. Do you willing to make bug report?

Comment: I've read about how TeX handles calculation by using `pt`, which seems... crazy for me. Should my example be treated as a bug, or just a normal overflow/underflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use default domain, i.e. `domain=-5:5`, than values of your function seems become becomes to big. This is somehow odd, see @ Torbjørn T. 1 comment.

To resolve this, you have two option:

- define domain between `xmin` and `xmax` (it has not sense to use wider domain), or
- define restriction for `y` (function) values:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        xlabel={\(x\)},
        xmin=-0.5,xmax=3.5,
        ylabel={\(y\)},
        ymin=-0.5,ymax=2.5,
        samples=200,
        restrict y to domain=-0.5:12,
        domain=-0.5:3.5,        
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},        
    no marks
    ]
        \addplot    {(x - 2)^3 + 1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

second case:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        xlabel={\(x\)},
        xmin=-0.5,xmax=3.5,
        ylabel={\(y\)},
        ymin=-0.5,ymax=2.5,
        samples=200,
        restrict y to domain=-0.5:12,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},        
    no marks
    ]
        \addplot    {(x - 2)^3 + 1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in the both cases the result is the same.

[image]